# The terminal process terminated with exit code: {0}

Tags: visual-studio

Utilizando Visual Studio Code e intentar arrancar un codigo, me aparece el error: "The terminal process terminated with exit code: {0}" y no me deja arrancar el código

Comment: Muestra el codigo de tu programa. Si no es imposible saber que pasa

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79427

Comment: @gbianchi, no creo que sea el código, creo que es un bug de VS Code

Comment: En Visual Studio ese mensaje no es un error. Te lo muestra cuando arrancas el programa desde Visual Studio (depurando) y el programa empieza y termina, indicándote que el main ha hecho un return con valor 0 cuando ha terminado.

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco ese issue esta cerrado como no reproducible...

Comment: yo he tenido bugs de Visual Studio que aparecían al depurar, parecía ser lo mismo